# Dynamically extend a class which returns the newly created class

Tags: javascript, c#, oop, inheritance

I'm not sure if the title question is exactly what needs to be done, but I'll explain. I have two classes Tile and extendTile. I want extendTile to create a new instance of Tile under a different class name so to speak.

### Example:

```
extendTile surfaceTile = new extendTile(Tile, {Layer: 1, Type: 0});

extTile grassTile = new surfaceTile("Grass");

extTile fireTile = new surfaceTile("Grass", {Damage: 0});
```

Here's the code I have that does exactly what I need in javascript.

```
function extendTile(Type, obj){
var newClass = function Tile(name, obj){
  this.name = name;
  console.log(name);
  if (obj) for (var key in obj){
    if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
      this[key] = obj[key];
    }
  }
}

var proto = new Type;

for (var key in obj)
{
  if (obj.hasOwnProperty(key))
  {
    proto[key] = obj[key];
  }
}

newClass.prototype = proto;
return newClass;}

var newTile = new extendTile(function() {}, {});
var SurfaceTile = new extendTile(newTile, {Layer: 0, Type: 0});
var extSurfaceTile = new extendTile(SurfaceTile, {Damage: 5}); //Will inherit the layer and type from SurfaceTile and extend it with Damage as well
var nameTheTile = new extSurfaceTile("fire");
```

This is for a Tilemap editor that I want to create specifically for a game I'm making. The reason why I want to be able to expand on objects like above is so that they can be modified as well as addons made and what not. It would be easier to expand on a class and dynamically create it, rather then creating an entire class from scratch (Prototypical inheritance).

I think I'm really thinking about this in the wrong manner, and should think about it in another approach but I'm not quite sure what approach would be best in this case. I know I will need to extend a base class though.

Comment: Have you looked at [ExpandoObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Comment: This seems like the XY problem. Why do you think you need this? C# is a statically typed language, so even though this can be achieved, it is not at all common c# code and you are likely approaching it the wrong way

Comment: @itsme86 - I have indeed. I was wondering if it could be done with just Object-Oriented without the use of Prototypical inheritance (ExpandoObject is similar to that if I'm correct?)

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto - What would the better approach be? If you don't mind me asking.

Comment: That would depend on the actual problem you want to solve, that's why I asked if you could provide some more info on your requirements

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I have edited the information down the bottom to include the reason why I wanted to do this

Comment: Why can't consumers extend your tile class? Or create a tile that has composes various attributes (damage, layer etc).

Comment: @EvanTrimboli How would I make it to extend a tile class with "various" attributes as I always thought that classes in c# have properties that are set in stone. 

Wouldn't they need to create an entire new class that wouldn't be dynamic? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Like I said, I think I'm thinking about this the entirely wrong way

Comment: You're right, if you extend the class then the properties are set. However how would your code use or infer meaning from those extra properties if they are entirely arbitrary?

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Oh wow, I get entirely what your saying. Why would I access a property that I don't even know what it's for...

Ummm, can I mark that as an answer some how. You clarified it a lot, I am going about it the wrong way. I should use the properties that my  code infers, properties can be null, but not added as how would I infer them! Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a base tile class that includes the potential modifiers that you want. Providing arbitrary properties isn't really useful for you, because if you're referring to a generic tile, then you have no way of knowing what those arbitrary properties are going to be, so you can't consume them in any meaningful way.

Instead of only providing static numbers, you may want to make it a bit more dynamic, allow the consumer to configure how those attributes are applied. Something like this:

```
interface ITileDamage
{
    int ApplyDamage(Tile t);
}

public class Tile
{
    int Layer { get; set; }
    ITileDamage Damage { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for that! I need to research more on how interfaces work, as I've never seen them used in this way - Thank you again.